# [__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c2ccb0 in ABRecordSetValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, runtime-error, unrecognized-selector

[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c2ccb0

I am getting this error in my code when I am trying to put a contact in address book. Appreciate any solution

```
     NSArray *names=[test componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSLog(@"Count:%d,%d",[names count],[test length],[names objectAtIndex:0],[names objectAtIndex:1] );
        //Works fine, a sample output-> For String:John Smith ; Count:2,10,John,Smith

        //CFStringRef temp; //for troubleshooting

    switch([names count])
    {
     case 1:ABRecordSetValue(self.person12,kABPersonFirstNameProperty,(__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)([names objectAtIndex:0]), NULL);
                                break;
     case 2: // Error occurs in case 2 as count is 2
     {

      //Commented region is what I tried out as an alternative but didnt work
     /*temp=(__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)((NSString*)[names objectAtIndex:0]);
                                ABRecordSetValue(self.person12,kABPersonFirstNameProperty,(CFTypeRef)temp,NULL);

    temp=(__bridge_retained CFStringRef)((NSString*)[[names objectAtIndex:1] substringToIndex:[[names objectAtIndex:1] length]-1]);
                               ABRecordSetValue(self.person12,kABPersonLastNameProperty,temp,NULL);*/

ABRecordSetValue(self.person12,kABPersonFirstNameProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)([names objectAtIndex:0]),NULL);// Error occurs after the execution of breakpoint here

ABRecordSetValue(self.person12,kABPersonLastNameProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)([[names objectAtIndex:1] substringToIndex:[[names objectAtIndex:1] length]-1]),NULL);
     break;
      }



    default:
       {
    ABRecordSetValue(self.person12,kABPersonFirstNameProperty,(__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)([names objectAtIndex:0]),NULL);
                                ABRecordSetValue(self.person12,kABPersonMiddleNameProperty,(__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)([names objectAtIndex:1]),NULL);
                                test=@"";
         for(int j=2;j<[names count];j++)
              test=[test stringByAppendingString:[names objectAtIndex:j]];

        test=[test substringToIndex:[test length]- 1];
                                ABRecordSetValue(self.person12,kABPersonLastNameProperty,(__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)test,NULL);
         break;
       }
     }
```

Comment: It means you are trying to use an `NSString` as an `NSDate` and the runtime doesn't like it.  Check your variables.

Comment: No NSDate, I am trying to set the string in name to my kABPersonFirstNameProperty

Comment: The problem is that you are using an `NSString` *somewhere* that expects an `NSDate`.  It might not even be here if you have concurrent operations running at the same time. Post the stack trace.

Comment: [__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - You are trying to call timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate on a NSString object somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the ABRecordRef
ie,

```
self.person12=ABPersonCreate();
```

also

initialize the address Book

```
self.addressBook=ABAddressBookCreate();
```

this will solve the problem !